# Editing a single form field with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form field in a view that is separate from my initial form. I want the person using the application to be able to edit a single field without having to pull up the entire form. My code is as follows

```
     <%= form_for :user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'update' } do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :barcode %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Register' %>
     <% end %>
```

When trying to submit the changes to the specified form field I receive an error on the create method I believe. It redirects me to the user controller with the proper id but gives me the following error.

```
 Unknown action
 The action '1' could not be found for UsersController
```

I have tried changing the method from update to create, but then it brings up the blank form, I just want to be able to edit the specified field without having to re-create the form and get the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the user object to the form.
Try also using the path helper generated by the routes:

```
     <%= form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

Comment: being `user_path(user)` the standard url for a `user`, it can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped shed some light on what my issue was. No only was I not using the @user variable in my view, but I had the Instance Variable in the wrong def statement. this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%= form_for(@user), :url => url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'update') do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :barcode %>
     <%= f.submit, 'Register' %>
 <% end %>
```

It should work now...

Comment: The @user variable isn't a part of this views controller. I am attempting to edit the user form from an accounts view. With an association of user has_one account and account belongs_to user. My accounts controller is as follows:

Comment: Hi.. If your form is related to a different resource you need to provide the URL. Let me edit the answer for you...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had to specify my @user instance variable in my update statement. Thanks for your help, this helped me out.